# Woocommerce How to get Term id from multiple slugs in css

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

Good Day,

I want to have a custom CSS for certain woo-commerce product category pages, to exclude the sidebar and make the content full width of the page. now I can get the CSS to work on these pages but I have over 450 categories. is there a way to make the term-id dynamic for excluded categories

the script I have so far is as follows

```
if ( !is_product_category( array( 'cat1','cat3','cat4','cat6') ) ) {
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<style>
 /*Hide SideBar*/
#primary {
     width: 100%!important; 
    border-right: 0px!important;
}
.term-1 .ast-right-sidebar #secondary,.term-3 .ast-right-sidebar #secondary,.term-4 .ast-right-sidebar #secondary,.term-6 .ast-right-sidebar #secondary{
    
    border-left: 0px!important
}
 .term-1.sidebar-main,.term-3 .sidebar-main,.term-4 .sidebar-main,.term-6 .sidebar-main {
    display:none!important
}
.term-1 #secondary,.term-3 #secondary,.term-4 #secondary,.term-6 #secondary {
    display: none!important;
    border-right: 0px solid #eee!important;
}
.term-1 .widget-area .secondary,.term-3 .widget-area .secondary,.term-4 .widget-area .secondary,.term-6 .widget-area .secondary
{
  display: none!important;

}
.term-1 .ast-right-sidebar #primary,.term-3 .ast-right-sidebar #primary,.term-4 .ast-right-sidebar #primary,.term-6 .ast-right-sidebar #primary {
    border-right: 0px solid #eee!important;
}
</style>
<?php } );
}
```

I would like to dynamically add the term-id to the CSS so that the CSS is more compact and does not get too long. any suggestions, please

Comment: _"dynamically add the term-id to the CSS"_ is rather the wrong approach here, IMHO. You should rather use a hook to add a class to the body element, when the requested content matches one of those terms. And then in your stylesheet, you use _one_ selector for each of the different elements you need to manipulate, when body has that class. `body.no-sidebar .ast-right-sidebar #secondary { border-left: 0px!important; } body.no-sidebar .sidebar-main { display:none!important; } ...`

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the help see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

The first thing I did is make a code snippet that you can copy and paste into the functions.php page of your child's theme or use plugins like code snippet. so when your theme updates you do not lose any of your code.

the first part that I did was as follows, I added this CSS to the body of the page.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'add_custom_body_class');

function add_custom_body_class($classes){
   if(is_product_category(array( 'cat1','cat3','cat4','cat6'))){
     $classes[] = 'your_new_class_here';
   }
   return $classes;
}
```

then I create a new snippet where I will add the class into the header now keep in mind that you do not want to have this code on every page so we will also add the is_product_category to the snippet to show code only when we are on that page

```
if ( !is_product_category( array( 'cat1','cat3','cat4','cat6') ) ) {
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<style>
 /*Hide SideBar*/
body.your_new_class_here .ast-right-sidebar #secondary { border-left: 0px!important; } 
body.your_new_class_here .sidebar-main { display:none!important; }  
#primary {
     width: 100%!important; 
    border-right: 0px!important;
}
#secondary {
    display: none!important;
    border-right: 0px solid #eee!important;
}
</style>
<?php } );
}
```

What this does is add the CSS classes to the pages that you specified, hope this helped someone else

Comment: _"What this does is add the CSS classes to the pages that you specified"_ - you don't _have_ to write this as inline CSS only into those pages, you could also just put it into the main stylesheet of your theme directly (assuming it's a custom theme.) The `body.your_new_class_here` part of those selectors prevents these rules from applying on any pages where body does not have that class.